# insert table in WordPress database

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to insert a table into WordPress database while plugin activated.         I have used this code but it is not working. This code should create a table while plugin gets activated, but in my WordPress when I activate the plugin, the code works, but table is not being created in the database.

How can I create the table in WordPress database while  plugin activated?

I have use the below code for my plugin

```
class createtabel {
    function __construct() {
        register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'create_plugin_database_table' );
    }

    public static function create_plugin_database_table() {
        global $wpdb;
        $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'wp_productqa';
        $sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_name (
        QA_id mediumint(9) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        Product_ID varchar(50) NOT NULL,
        Username varchar(50)NOT NULL,
        Useremail varchar(50) NOT NULL,
        comment varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY  (QA_id)
        );";
        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
        dbDelta( $sql );
    }
}
```

Comment: how you can call this class function like that

Comment: class ProductQA
{
function createdatabase()
     {
    $classdb= new createtabel();
    register_activation_hook( __FILE__, array( $this) );
     }
}
$productQAObject->createdatabase();

Comment: $createTable = new createtabel; 
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, array($createTable, create_plugin_database_table));

Comment: but I want to use from another page one is my productqa.php page and other is classdb in productqa page include classdb and call classdb object

Comment: Use WordPress built in `$wpdb` class for database calls: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure register_activation_hook is called.

For instance, in your plugin definition file you may:

```
$createTable = new createtabel;
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, array($createTable, 'create_plugin_database_table'));
```

BTW, in the createtabel class you can create your table with:

```
$wpdb->query($sql);
```

Is that your intention also to have

```
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'wp_productqa';
```

which in most likelihood (assuming prefix is wp_)will have:

```
$table_name = 'wp_wp_productqa';
```

Comment: 1. remove the __construct method in createtabel. 2. You have the createtabel class in your plugin definition file if not you must load it with include or require. 3. create an instance of createtabel class with new createtabel. 4. register_activation_hook as defined above 5. activate the plugin if it is not activated; or if it is you must deactivate then activate.

Comment: hello bro  I  can follow your step but still it's not working

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code while activate your plugin it will create new table in your database.

```
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'install_covercarousel');
```

Define this above hook in globally where your file coding has been started.

Also please dont' use `public static function` just add `function and functioname` like this `function abs(){}`

After changed code look like this

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'create_plugin_database_table' );
function create_plugin_database_table() {
            global $wpdb;
            $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'wp_productqa';
            $sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_name (
            QA_id mediumint(9) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
            Product_ID varchar(50) NOT NULL,
            Username varchar(50)NOT NULL,
            Useremail varchar(50) NOT NULL,
            comment varchar(255) NOT NULL,
            PRIMARY KEY  (QA_id)
            );";
            require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
            dbDelta( $sql );
        }
```

Comment: hello I use this code in my plugin but it's give error like:"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'register_activation_hook' (T_STRING), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) in D:\Xampp\htdocs\testwordpress\wp-content\plugins\ProductQA\classdb.php on line 3"

Comment: Yes becuase of you had remove your class name declaration from your file so it will gives you error so please use this code as per your structure of plugin.

Comment: No, i can not remove class name

Comment: can we discuss this on stackoverflow live chat ?

Here is chat window link http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127362/insert-table-in-to-wordpress-database

Comment: Here is the chat room live link http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127362/insert-table-in-to-wordpress-database

Comment: sorry I don't have 20 reputations so I can not chat with you

Comment: Ok, So we can't do anything Thanks